# updated from cordova 3.9.2 to 4.0.0 plugins are not working

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

After I updated my ios to cordova 4.0.0, my plugins were not working correctly. First this happened

http://a.disquscdn.com/uploads/mediaembed/images/2922/9561/original.jpg

after I deleted, added ios platform, and it worked. But all my plugins were not working correctly. For example the keyboard, I couldn't use it. Orientation was locked on portrait and it used up to 2 gb of memory.

I am really confuse of what is going on here, I have not got much experience with cordova, or understand of the gulp  or bower.

Thank in advance.

Comment: update the plugins

Comment: I did update the plugins, but nothing had improved. Actually I updated everything included gulp, bower and ionic cli. I checked sudo npm -g outdated, then sudo npm -g update. Also the local files. Everything broke apart when I got to Cordova platform add ios@4.0.0. Also thank you for ur reply.

Comment: Hi jcesarmobile, you are right!! I have to uninstall the plugins and reinstall them. Because somehow it didn't pick up in the iOS.json. The plugins for the orientation and splashscreen caused a bit of problem. Appearancely there is a change in the timing of the orientation if I remember it right. So it doesn't work now :(.